# Is there a version compatibility issue between Spark/Hadoop/Scala/Java/Python?

Tags: python, java, scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

I'm getting an error while running spark-shell command through cmd but unfortunately without any luck so far. I have Python/Java/Spark/Hadoop(winutils.exe)/Scala installed with versions as below:

- Python: 3.7.3
- Java: 1.8.0_311
- Spark: 3.2.0
- Hadoop(winutils.exe):2.5x
- scala sbt: sbt-1.5.5.msi

I followed below steps and ran spark-shell (`C:\Program Files\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\bin>`) through cmd:

1. Create `JAVA_HOME` variable: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin`
2. Add the following part to your path: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
3. Create `SPARK_HOME` variable: `C:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\bin`
4. Add the following part to your path: `%SPARK_HOME%\bin`
5. The most important part Hadoop path should include bin file before `winutils.exe` as the following: `C:\Hadoop\bin` Sure you will locate `winutils.exe` inside this path.
6. Create `HADOOP_HOME` Variable: `C:\Hadoop`
7. Add the following part to your path: `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`

Am I missing out on anything? I've posted my question with error details in another thread ([spark-shell command throwing this error: SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69923603/spark-shell-command-throwing-this-error-sparkcontext-error-initializing-sparkc))

Comment: As you can see by the name `spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2`, your spark version is compatible with hadoop 3.2 version. Maybe you can upgrade your hadoop version to Hadoop 3.2.2.   In our production environment, we use  java 1.8.0_282, hadoop 3.2.2, spark: spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2, scala scala-2.12.13 and sbt: sbt-1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

You went the difficult way in installing everything by hand. You may need Scala too, be extremely vigilant with the version you are installing, from your example it seems like it’s Scala 2.12.

But you are right: Spark is extremely demanding in term of version matching. Java 8 is good. Java 11 is ok too, but not any more recent version.

Alternatively, you can:

1. Try a very simple app like in https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01
2. Use Docker with a pre made image, and if your goal is to do Python, I would recommend an image with Jupiter and Spark preconfigured together.